# Unable tor create stripe token

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

Hi i am about to create stripe token in angular application. getting error **Cannot read property 'createToken' of undefined**

In **index..html** i have added

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

In component.ts :

```
  (<any>window).Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: this.cardNumber,
        exp_month: this.expiryMonth,
        exp_year: this.expiryYear,
        cvc: this.cvc
      }, (status: number, response: any) => {
        if (status === 200) {
          this.message = `Success! Card token ${response.card.id}.`;
        } else {
          this.message = response.error.message;
        }
      });
```

Comment: `(<any>window).Stripe.card` is undefined

Comment: then how to create token using angular

Comment: Hi Sudhir, you first have to initialize Stripe.js using your publishable key as shown here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/initializing. After that, you would need to create a token using this method here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement. I should point out that PaymentMethods are the new recommend approach for tokenizing details. Also, you would most likely need to mount a card element in order to collect the details first as outlined here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder